# Use the bundled USB-C cable with Target Mode

Tags: usb

Can I use the white USB-C cable provided with new MacBook Pro to copy files from my MacBook Pro to another one, even if the transfer rate is poor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - according to Apple:

**Compared with Apple USB-C Charge Cable**

The Apple USB-C Charge Cable is longer (2m) and also supports charging, but data-transfer speed is limited to 480Mbps (USB 2.0) and it doesn't support video. The Apple Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) cable has Thunderbolt  logo on the sleeve of each connector. Either cable can be used with the Apple USB-C Power Adapter.

See [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208368) for reference.